# What is the Label property under the identity inspector in Xcode 4?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, uibutton

The place holder text for the Label property is 'Xcode Specific Label', which when googled turns up nothing.

I assumed it used for identifying the UI element in your code by it's 'Xcode Specific Label' and not the actual text that the button displays in the UI. If so I am interesting in using it in my code since I have buttons with similar functions whose actions I want to send to the same method and differentiate between the two with the sender property by name. I understand that you can do this through the object id but I think that using a name would be clearer. How would I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Label field identifies the UI element in Xcode. If you name the UI element using the Label text field, you'll notice that element's name changes in the object list, which is to the left of the canvas.

The Label field doesn't do much with regard to code. It exists to make things more convenient in Xcode. In fact, the whole Identity section of the identity inspector exists to make things more convenient for you in Xcode. Suppose you have three text fields in your window. Giving each text field a different label makes it easier to identify each text field.

Comment: To clarify: if you want a reference to a UI element, you must create and connect an IBOutlet to it.

Comment: @Joshua Nozzi - that's not entirely true - you can reference the UI Element by assigning a tag under the Attributes inspector.

Comment: Is this an iOS difference I'm unaware of? Is there some mechanism to get any UI element via its tag?

Comment: @Joshua Apparently this is possible. See the answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413653/can-the-value-of-the-identity-label-be-accessed-in-code)

Comment: Naming objects in Xcode 3 was much easier. I tried to use "Xcode Specific Label" once to name the object in the list and it did not update in the object list as I hoped it would. So I deleted my text that I entered into "Xcode Specific Label" and moved on looking for a way to name objects.  Turns out it would have worked if I would have changed the focus to some other panel or something.  If you try to set the "Xcode Specific Label" and it does nothing, click in the object list.  Not sure what has to lose/gain focus for the object list to update.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

just the name you typed for the view in the Document Outline,It's a convenient way for you to identify the views in Xcode. as the image shows: I update the view's name to contentView, that means the view is the scrollView's ContentView.