# Can the value of the Identity Label be accessed in code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have a number of labels in Interface builder which all have their identity label set (`Identity inspector` > `Identity` > `Label`.

I would now like to access these labels in my code. Is this generally possible or is this only present within Interface builder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would not be possible to access each labels `Identity inspector` > `Identity` > `Label` in your code.  To better understand what the Identity label does, check out this link:

[Label property in identity inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141717/what-is-the-label-property-under-the-identity-inspector-in-xcode-4)

It would probably be better if you just accessed the label using the defined IBOulet.  If you want to try something that is similar you could just set the `tag` property like so:

```
label.tag = 1;
```

Give each label a unique tag and you should be able to access it using

`UILabel *label = [self.view viewWithTag:1];`

Comment: And why would you recommend this over having an IBOutlet for the label?

Comment: That's a good question.  I can't believe I just glossed over that.

Comment: How does one tag in the visual editor? If I have many many objects, it would be a mess to define each one by IBOulet.

Comment: It's in the `Attributes inspector` > `View` > `Tag`.

Comment: @Jasarien (ok so it's an old comment, but i couldn't resist:) because by using tags you can do neat things like "for (t=10;t<100;t++) {[[self.view viewWithTag:t] setHidden:YES];}". Just saying.

Comment: @unsynchronized maybe, but you can put IBOutlet objects in an array and do the same thing, no?

Comment: yes. but one requires extra storage, extra code to put it in the array. the tag property already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can give different tags to your labels and then access labels by tags.