# What is the XCode Interface Builder "Document" Section

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I understand the "Xcode Specific Label" section.

What I **don't** understand is the "Notes" section.  I've played around with it and can't see any discernable effect.

*Can anyone explain this?*

[image]

Comment: For an idea of a practical use of notes see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207088/how-to-add-copyright-information-to-a-nib-file/11208398#11208398

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141717/what-is-the-label-property-under-the-identity-inspector-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 2):

It's saving an attributed string with a key of `userComments` to the storyboard file.

```
<attributedString key="userComments">
    <fragment content="These are the comments I entered in the notes section of Interface Builder">
        <attributes>
            <font key="NSFont" size="11" name="LucidaGrande"/>
            <paragraphStyle key="NSParagraphStyle" alignment="left" lineBreakMode="wordWrapping" baseWritingDirection="natural"/>
        </attributes>
    </fragment>
</attributedString>
```

I don't know of any practical use of this, though. It would be nice to be able to retrieve this programmatically, though.